# While uploading Express.js + Admin.js project to Vercel it returns Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: express, vercel, deploying, adminjs

I am trying to deploy my **express** project with **adminjs** admin panel to **vercel**, but when I do it, it gives the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/task/back/node_modules/adminjs/lib/locale/de/translation.json' imported from /var/task/back/node_modules/adminjs/lib/locale/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:332:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:995:10)
    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:939:12)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1181:79)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 312.34 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

In my localhost, the whole programs works correct. I do not have any problem with *import* or *require* keyword, I have added *"type":**"module*** to my **package.json** file.

My **vercel.json ** file:
[**vercel.json**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXRQT.png)
[**project tree (do not pay attention to node_modules folder, it does not contain an error it is buging**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2zk2.png)

I do not know what is the problem and why I cannot upload my project to **vercel**, however when I remove **admin.js** from my project it deploys and works as expected.

Hope you will be able to help me. Thank you in advance!

I have tried to change my **vercel.json** file, but I did not know what to change so that to fix my problem.

I also tried to write some code so that before building the program vercel would upload all important packages, but it did not help.

I was expecting everything to work without such an error